# Como deixar o Header e o Footer responsivo com Boostrap 4.1.1?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

**Problema no Header:**

- Não consigo deixar o último botão encostado do lado direito da página, como se fosse um navbar toogle.

  - Os textos dos selects "somem" ao diminuir as resoluções.

**Problema no Footer:**

- Os itens do footer ficam um em cima do outro ao diminuir as resoluções.

**Observação:**

A responsividade é tanto na parte do container, quanto na parte dos textos dos selects, pois eles "somem" em display menores...

**Prototipo de como deve ficar:**

[image: prototype]
**Código:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="...">
    <meta name="author" content="Thiago De Bonis Carvalho Saad Saud">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet/colors.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontawesome/fontawesome-all.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body class="aliansce-bg-dark-grey">
        <header>
                <div class="container-fluid p-2">
                    <div class="d-flex flex-row">
                        <form action="" class="form-inline rounded bg-white">
                            <div class="col">
                                <!-- Indicadores Custom-Select -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label for="select-indicadores" class="input-group-text bg-transparent border-0">
                                            <i class="fas fa-chart-line aliansce-text-grey"></i>
                                        </label>
                                        <select class="custom-select border-0" id="select-indicadores" required>
                                            <option value="null" selected disabled>Escolha o Indicador</option>
                                            <optgroup label="INDICADORES">
                                                <option value="null">Vendas Absoluta</option>
                                            </optgroup>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <!-- Shopppings Custom-Select -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="input-group">
                                        <label for="select-shoppings" class="input-group-text bg-transparent border-0">
                                            <i class="far fa-building" aliansce-text-grey></i>
                                        </label>
                                        <select class="custom-select border-0" id="select-shoppings" required>
                                                <option value="null" selected disabled>Escolha o Shopping</option>
                                                <optgroup label="RIO DE JANEIRO">
                                                    <option value="null">Bangu</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Boulevard Campos</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Carioca</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Caixas</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Passeio</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Pátio Alcântara</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Santa Cruz</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Grande Rio</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Leblon</option>
                                                    <option value="null">São Gonçalo</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Via Parque</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="MINAS GERAIS">
                                                    <option value="null">Boulevard Belo Horizonte</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="SÃO PAULO">
                                                    <option value="null">Boulevard Bauru</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Continental</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Santana Parque</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Praça Nova Araçatuba</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Santa Úrsula</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Taboão</option>
                                                    <option value="null">West Plaza</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="ESPIRITO SANTO">
                                                    <option value="null">Boulevard Vila Velha</option>
                                                </optgroup> 
                                                <optgroup label="SANTA CATARINA">
                                                    <option value="null">Floripa</option>
                                                </optgroup>    
                                                <optgroup label="RIO GRANDE DO SUL">
                                                    <option value="null">Praça Nova Santa Maria</option>
                                                </optgroup>  
                                                <optgroup label="MATO GROSSO">
                                                    <option value="null">Goiabeiras</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="DISTRITO FEDERAL">
                                                    <option value="null">Boulevard Brasília</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="BAHIA">
                                                    <option value="null">Boulevard Feira de Satana</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Boulevard Vitória da Conquista</option>
                                                    <option value="null">Bahia</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                <optgroup label="ALAGOAS">
                                                    <option value="null">Parque Maceió</option>
                                                </optgroup>
                                                 <optgroup label="CEARÁ">
                                                     <option value="null">Parangaba</option>
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                    <optgroup label="PARÁ">
                                                        <option value="null">Boulevard Belém</option>
                                                        <option value="null">Parque Belém</option>
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <!-- Data Custom-Select -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <label for="select-data" class="input-group-text bg-transparent border-0">
                                                    <i class="far fa-calendar-alt aliansce-text-grey"></i>
                                                </label>
                                                <select class="custom-select border-0" id="select-data" required>
                                                    <option value="null" selected disabled>Escolha a Data</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col">
                                        <!-- Visão Custom-Select -->
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <label for="select-visao" class="input-group-text bg-transparent border-0">
                                                    <i class="far fa-eye aliansce-text-grey"></i>
                                                </label>
                                                <select class="custom-select border-0" id="select-visao" required>
                                                    <option value="null" selected disabled>Escolha a Visão</option>
                                                    <optgroup label="ABL">
                                                        <option value="null">Lazer</option>
                                                        <option value="null">Lojas Âncoras</option>
                                                        <option value="null">MegaLojas</option>
                                                        <option value="null">Satélite</option>
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                    <optgroup label="ABRASCE">
                                                        <option value="null">----</option>
                                                    </optgroup>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg  aliansce-bg-green text-white"><i class="fab fa-searchengin fa-lg"></i></button>  
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class="col ml-5" style="background-color: red">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg aliansce-bg-green text-white"><i class="fab fa-searchengin fa-lg"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </header>






    <!--Footer Navegação-->
    <div class="fixed-bottom aliansce-bg-grey p-2">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2 d-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent"><img src="img/logo/aliansce-icon.svg" alt="Aliansce Logo" class="img-fluid w-25 text-white"><span class="ml-2 text-white">SOBRE</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 d-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent"><i class="fas fa-chart-line aliansce-text-green"></i><span class="ml-2 text-white">NÚMEROS</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 d-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent "><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag aliansce-text-green"></i><span class="ml-2 text-white">MARCAS</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 d-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent "><i class="fas fa-camera aliansce-text-green"></i><span class="ml-2 text-white">GALERIA</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 d-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent "><i class="fab fa-accusoft aliansce-text-green"></i><span class="ml-2 text-white">PLANTA</span></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-2 d-flex">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg bg-transparent  "><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt aliansce-text-green"></i><span class="ml-2 text-white">LOCAL</span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Javascript Config -->
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cara os ícones do rodapé não estão ficando um por cima do outro não, pelo menos no teste que fiz aqui. Já sobre o select o que vc pretende com eles? retirar completamente o texto em telas pequenas, colocar em forma de coluna um debaixo do outro, o que vc pretende?

Comment: @hugocsl os selects e o botão de search faz parte de um formulário de pesquisa, com os selects eu pretendo que fiquem visiveis os textos tanto para notebook-desktop e quanto para tablets, já os icones do footer, eles se sobrepoem quando eu diminuo para o tablet.